# R: Linking to data in package B from source code in package A

Tags: r, package

I'm building a new R package which has a lot of internal data. I decided to split the package into two pieces: A (houses the source code) and B (houses the data). This is in line with official CRAN policies. The data is crucial and the package cannot function without it.

I'm having trouble linking to the data in B from source code in A. All source code in A is in directory `R/` and all data in B is in directory `data/`. Let's assume that `dat` is the only data file in B. I tried the following:

1. Enable `LazyData: true` in the `DESCRIPTION` file for B, this exports the data files. In A, I access the data in source code via `B::dat`. PROBLEM: `R CMD check` raises a NOTE that `B::dat` has not been defined, and CRAN maintainers claim that this is bad practice.
2. Save all data in B into `sysdata.rda` in the `R/` directory and refer to it using `B:::dat` from A. PROBLEM: CRAN maintainers claim that this is bad practice since all data should be in `data/`, not in `R/`. Also, this way you cannot document the data files in `man/`.
3. Data in B cannot be exported using the `NAMESPACE` file using the `export(dat)` command.
4. `data(dat,package="B")` loads the data but into the Global Environment, but as internal data it should not be visible to the user so this won't work.
5. `data(dat,package="B",envir=environment())` loads the data into the local environment of the function call, but every time the function is called (this can be many times), it takes a long time to load the data making calculations too slow. I also tried loading into the package namespace directly but those namespaces are locked and this is not allowed. How can we get the data to load directly into the package namespace?

Any suggestions on how to go about this? What is the correct way to do this? Ideally the data is in the `data/` directory in package B and the source code in package A has no problems in accessing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution that works:

In Package A's `DESCRIPTION` file, it should contain `Depends: B`. I found that using `Imports: B` will *not* work for importing data files unless they are in `sysdata.rda`. Also, package B's `NAMESPACE` file should contain the following by default:

```
exportPattern(".")
```

This way you can refer to `dat` directly in any source code in package A.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it simple and be explicit:  `data(someData, package="A")`  ?

Having it work magically (as it does when data comes from the same package) may be possible; there are some packages (such as [SOAR](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=SOAR)) doing tricks with lazy-loading and on-demand loading.

*Edit:* Come to think about it, there are a number of *data* packages on CRAN. Did you study those?  Eg [TH.data](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=TH.data) was setup by Torsten for use in is package.  Isn't that your use case?  Maybe you'll find the relevant trick in its setup.

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated your solution, but doesn't quite work. Please see edited question above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an example of a data-only package. Got the answer from there. It now works flawlessly, was surprised that data packages need to be *Depended* on, not *Imported* from.

Comment: _Depends:_ alters the search path which is what you wanted.